# R boxplot with label-gap in splitted data

Tags: r, split, axis, label, boxplot

I have a dataset with lots of variables and i want to make boxplots showing a box-whisker for every year for different variables. So for example I have for all data a year-range from 2007-2015 and want a box whisker for every year for a certain variable.

No problem with that.

Now, if I split the data some variables only have values for the years 2007 and 2010... how do i make the boxplot look the same as the one for all data, with 2007, 2008, 2009... 2015 on the x axis and only boxwhiskers for the years 2007 and 2010 (as I only have data from these years for a certain variable)?!

Boxplot with all data:
[image]

Boxplot with selected values, but missing year:
[image]

Really hanging there, couln'd find anything yet on the web (mayby wrong search pattern)

Thx

Comment: Try the `ylim` parameter in your plot function. E.g. `boxplot(x,y,ylim=c(0,300)`

Comment: problem is not the y-axes but the x-axes. in the second graph 2013 is missing (due to no values in this data-split), i want it to show it anyways (with no boxwhisker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit factors to get what you want.

```
## Example data
dd = data.frame(y = rnorm(40))
dd$x = factor(c(1:3, 5), levels=1:5)
```

Notice the `x` just takes the values `1`, `2`, `3`, and `5` but has levels 1 to 5. Running a standard boxplot function gives exactly what you are after:

```
boxplot(y ~ x, data=dd)
```

[image]

Comment: that worked, thanks for your help! Wouldn't have figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "at" argument in boxplot()

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(2000: 2005, 2013), each = 10), y = rnorm(70))
boxplot(y~x, data = df, at = c(2000:2005, 2013))
```